# ABAQUS-python - writing ODB results to file

Tags: python-2.7, abaqus

I have the following script to open ABAQUS ODB file and get displacements and coordinates of a specific node set. I can get these to print on screen but need help to write them to a file (.xlsx, .cvs, .dat or .txt) for postprocess. I'm new to scripting with abaqus so any help would be great appreciated. Code is currently as follows:

```
from odbAccess import *
from numpy import array

odb = openOdb(path='Test_3.odb')
lastFrame = odb.steps['Step-1'].frames[1]

displacement = lastFrame.fieldOutputs['U']
coords=lastFrame.fieldOutputs['COORD']

NodeSet_x = odb.rootAssembly.instances['CFRP_SKIN_TS-1'].nodeSets['NODE_SET_X_AXIS']
NodeSet_y = odb.rootAssembly.instances['CFRP_SKIN_TS-1'].nodeSets['NODE_SET_Y_AXIS']
    
centerDisplacement_x = displacement.getSubset(region=NodeSet_x)
NodeCoord_x = coords.getSubset(region=NodeSet_x)

centerDisplacement_y = displacement.getSubset(region=NodeSet_y)
NodeCoord_y = coords.getSubset(region=NodeSet_y)

for v in centerDisplacement_x.values:
    disp_out = v.nodeLabel, v.data[2]
    print (disp_out)

for c in NodeCoord_x.values:
    coord_out = c.nodeLabel, c.data[0], c.data[1], c.data[2]    
    print (coord_out)

odb.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, it just basic file read write thing. But anyways. 
For more details on how to write the data in text file in python refer below links.
[Click here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-writing-text-files-python/) to know about opening and closing files in python. 
[Click here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-output-formatting/) to know about writing format in python.

Please follow below simple lines of code which works for any number of node sets.

```
node_sets = ['NODE_SET_X_AXIS','NODE_SET_Y_AXIS']
for node_set in node_sets:
   fileName = '%s.dat'%node_set
   fout = open(fileName,'w')
   nset = odb.rootAssembly.instances['CFRP_SKIN_TS-1'].nodeSets[node_set]
   field = odb.steps['Step-1'].frames[1].fieldOutputs['U'].getSubset(region=nset)
   for val in field.values:
       data = val.data
       node_label = val.nodeLabel
       node = odb.rootAssembly.instances['CFRP_SKIN_TS-1'].getNodeFromLabel(label=node_label)
       coords = node.coordinates
       fout.write('%10d%14.4E%14.4E%14.4E%16.4E%16.4E%16.4E\n'%tuple([node_label,]+list(coords)+list(data)))
   
   fout.close()
```

This code creates a separate text file for each node set.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated and for the links.